# XML Document read in as Latin1 but half converted to UTF-8

Tags: java, xml

I'm hitting my head off a brick wall with a bizarre problem that I *know* there will be an obvious answer to, but I can't see if for the life of me.  It's all to do with encoding.  Before the code, a simple description: I want to take in an XML document which is Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) encoded, and then send the thing *completely unchanged* over an HttpURLConnection.  I have a small test class and the raw XML which shows my problem.  The XML file contains a Latin1 character 0xa2 (a cent character), which is invalid UTF-8 - I'm deliberately using this as my test case.  The XML declaration is ISO-8859-1.  I can read it in no bother, but then when I want to convert the org.w3c.dom.Document to a byte[] array to send down the HttpURLConnection, the 0xa2 character gets converted to the UTF-8 encoded cent character (0xc2 0xa2), and the declaration stays as ISO-8859-1.  In other words, it's converted to two characters - totally wrong.

The code which does this:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream( "input-file" );
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware( true );
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse( input );

Source source = new DOMSource( document );
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Result result = new StreamResult( baos );
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform( source, result );
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( "output-file" );
fos.write( bytes );
```

I'm just writing it to a file at the moment while I figure out what on earth is converting this character.  The input-file has 0xa2, the output-file contains 0xc2 0xa2.  One way to fix this is to put this line in the 2nd last block:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
```

However, not all XML documents that I'll be dealing with will be Latin1; most, indeed, will be UTF-8 when they come in.  I'm assuming I shouldn't have to be working out what the encoding is such that I feed that in to the transformer though?  I mean, surely it should be working this out for itself, and I'm just doing something else wrong?

A thought had occurred to me that I could just query the document to find out the encoding and thus the extra line could just do the trick:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, document.getInputEncoding());
```

However, I then determined that this *wasn't* the answer, as document.getInputEncoding() returns a different String if I run it in a terminal on the linux box in comparison to when I run it within Eclipse on my Mac.

Any hints would be appreciated.  I fully accept I'm missing out on something obvious.

Comment: Have you tried document.getXmlEncoding() as opposed to document.getInputEncoding()?

Comment: Are you using a really old version of Xerces?  It had a bug in this area: http://marc.info/?l=xerces-j-user&m=117066258213990&w=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, by default, xml documents are written as utf-8, so you need to explicitly tell the Transformer to use a different encoding.  your last edit is the "trick" to doing this such that it always matches the input xml encoding:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, document.getXmlEncoding());
```

the only question is, do you really *need* to maintain the input encoding?

Comment: If I don't maintain the encoding, the 0xa2 byte is changed to two bytes (0xc2 0xa2), but the XML document declaration stays as ISO-8859-1.  This means that the content of the XML changes, and that's clearly undesirable.

Comment: Actually, I've now discovered that this is a red herring - document.getInputEncoding() gives me a different result if I run this from a terminal than it does if I run it from within Eclipse!  Therefore, it's not the answer at all, and I'll edit my question to point this out.

Comment: @Kenny - are you saying that if you don't set _any_ properties on the Transformer, it is outputting the xml encoding as "ISO-8859-1"?

Comment: it seems to be the opposite, in that it's an ISO-8859-1 encoded document with an ISO-8859-1 in the declaration, but the data is then transformed to UTF-8. However, as noted by GreenieMeanie, if I use the getXmlEncoding() method to set the encoding property, it all works fine. It just bemused me that this wasn't being done automatically... I mean, the document _knows_ that it is ISO-8859-1 from the declaration, so why is it converting the data to UTF-8? It just seems odd to me.  But I suspect I'm not fully understanding something - at least I know how to get the right encoding now.

Comment: @Kenny - maybe i'm not understanding what you are saying, but like i said, the xml tools in java (and many xml tools) output the xml documents as utf8 encoded by default.  so yes, any xml document you generate (regardless of how it was originally encoded) will be output as utf8.  this is by design and almost always the best choice.

Comment: it just seems odd to me, therefore, than java is outputting the values in the XML in UTF-8 but leaving the declaration as ISO-8859-1, despite knowing that it read in the XML document as ISO-8859-1.  In other words, it's deliberately breaking the content of the XML.  I could understand it if it changed the values to UTF-8 *and* changed the declaration, but doing one but not the other?

Comment: @Kenny, I ran into the same issue with those two encoding. Where you able to resolve this problem w/o a workaround reasonably?

Comment: @Michael-O - I think the answer that I accepted is the answer, rather than a workaround; I think I was just using the wrong method.  getXmlEncoding() was what I needed to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Kenny, I do not think that this is a solution. If transformer produces UTF-8 by default it must alter the XML declaration. Everything else is, imho, incorrect.

Comment: @Michael: i agree that it should alter the declaration as well. has anybody found a fix for this? the problem arises only if DomSource is used. if you use streamSource the xml-declaration is altered correctly

Answer (score 1):

Why not just open it with a normal FileInputStream and stream the bytes to the output stream directly from that? Why do you need to load it into DOM format in memory if you are just sending it byte for byte over an HttpURLConnection?

Edit: According to javadoc for Document, you should probably be using document.getXmlEncoding() to get what matches the encoding in the XML prolog.

Comment: It's a question that is implying the answer. He doesn't need to use the DOM API, just normal streams. This is the obvious thing he is missing out on, based on my assumption of his requirements.

Comment: It's because in reality, the XML won't be in a file; I am just using a file in this test case to easily load in a Document.  The actual system itself will have a Document that it gets from an external source, and needs to send that over an HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful - it's too long for a comment, but not really an answer.  From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output):

> The encoding attribute specifies the preferred encoding to use for
>   outputting the result tree. XSLT processors are required to respect
>   values of UTF-8 and UTF-16. For other values, if the XSLT processor
>   does not support the specified encoding it **may** signal an error; **if it
>   does not signal an error it should use UTF-8 or UTF-16 instead**.

You may want to test with "encoding=junk", as it were, to see what it does.

The valid values for Java are described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#ENCODING).  See also [IANA charsets](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets).

Comment: Hmm. So if it supports ISO-8859-1, you'd think it'd use it, if that was in the declaration? I shall go read that spec, thanks for the tip.